# UIButton custom image alpha

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some buttons close to each other in a logo shape, they are non rectangular shapes and I was wondering if I can exclude the transparent parts of the button from receiving touches, so that the elements behind it can receive the touches instead?.

Can you make the alpha parts of the button image not part of the button? , or , if the user touches these alpha parts, the button below will be tapped?

Comment: Your question is less explanatory, either provide pictorial view/code. Or provide more information about the same.

Comment: What is the question please?

Answer (score 0):

You would normally have to subclass UIButton, but luckily someone has taken care of this for you already:

https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton

This seems to be exactly what you're looking for.